# Where is Gnome Terminal in the Software Center?

Tags: xubuntu, software-center, gnome-terminal

If I do a search in the Software Center (in Xubuntu 17.10) for Gnome Terminal I can't find it. I've tried different search terms and nothing. Shouldn't it be there someplace?

I know I can install it via the command line, that's not the issue. It seems it should be in the Software Center someplace and if this is a bug or omission it should be corrected.

Comment: This is not the place to report a bug, if it is a bug... I don't have a Xubuntu 17.10 instance to poke around on, but have you updated the repository information?

Comment: Yes, the repository is up to date.